# Windows - Create Folder and sub folder based on date of filename

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a folder with a number of pdf files whereby the last 8 characters is the date of the document in the format YYYYMMDD, samples are:

File_YYYYMMDD
Test_Ref_YYYYMMDD
file.nr_YYYYMMDD

I am looking for a way to create a folder structure based on last 8 characters:
OutputFolder\Subfolder YYYY\Subfolder MM\File name remains the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to iterate through the source folder where the pdf files are, and using their `BaseName` (= filename without extension), get the year and month part.

Having those, creating the folder structure is a breaze in PowerShell:

```
$sourceFolder = 'D:\OriginalPath' # the path where your pdf files are
$destination  = 'D:\PdfFiles'     # the folder where the new folder structure should be created

# get the pdf files that have a basename ending with 8 digits
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter '*.pdf' -File | 
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '\d{8}$' } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        # split the year and month part of the file's basename
        $match = $_.BaseName -match '(\d{4})(\d{2})\d{2}$'
        $year, $month = $matches[1..2]
        # construct the folder path
        $targetFolder = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath "$year\$month"
        # if the target folder does not exist, create it
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $targetFolder -PathType Container)) {
            $null = New-Item -Path $targetFolder -ItemType Directory
        }
        # you probably now want to copy or move the file in that target folder
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $targetFolder
    }
```

Example of the source folder:

```
D:\ORIGINALPATH
    File_20200201.pdf
    File_20200327.pdf
    Test_Ref_20191127.pdf
```

After running the code:

```
D:\PDFFILES
+---2019
|   \---11
|           Test_Ref_20191127.pdf
|
\---2020
    +---02
    |       File_20200201.pdf
    |
    \---03
            File_20200327.pdf
```

Comment: @AlexJ Thanks, you too!